# No me respeta el formato de fecha

Tags: javascript, html

En el siguiente código pongo la fecha para que me la muestre como dd/mm/yyy pero me la muestra como mm/dd/yyy.

Alguna ayuda?

**Reportrange** es un **inout**

```
<input type="text" id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 210px"/>

function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange value').html(start.format("DD/MM/YYYY") + ' - ' + end.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Answer (score 0):

y si lo intentas de manera manual? seria de esta forma:

```
start.getDate() + "/" + (start.getMonth()+1) + "/" + start.getFullYear()
```

o incluso puedes optar por este

```
start.toLocaleDateString()
```

pero dependiendo de la configuracion del navegador te muestra el formato

Answer (score 0):

```js
let fecha = new Date()

    let dia = fecha.getDate()
    let mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1
    let year = fecha.getFullYear()

    if(mes < 10){
      console.log(`${dia}-0${mes}-${year}`)
    }else{
      console.log(`${dia}-${mes}-${year}`)
    }
```

Puedes probar de esta manera, a mí me funciona